# Remover parte de um texto no combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Tenho um combobox que leio um diretorio e trago os nomes dos arquivos encontratos:

saida:

```
demons.txt 
arch.txt 
elo.txt
```

até ai tudo ok,
mas não gostaria que no combobox aparecesse a extensao `.txt`, como remove-lá?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension):

```
Uses
  IOUtils;
// ....

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
   Arquivos: array[1..3] of string = ('demons.txt ','arch.txt ','elo.txt');
Var
   Arquivo: String;
begin
  ComboBox1.Clear;
  For Arquivo in Arquivos do 
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Arquivo));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: se tivesse por exemplo x arquivos, que podem ir sendo gerados, apagados...

Comment: Eu preencho o combo box com uma Tstringlist, como poderia passar ela como parametro?

Comment: @GuilhermeLima É só percorrer o `StringList` e ir adicionando no `Combobox` o item atual usando essa função. Veja: http://pastebin.com/tqvT1B2v

Comment: resolvido, obrigado :D